# Creating a "Chain Reaction" of colliders or triggers in Unity 2D

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm trying to create a 'Chain Reaction" of sorts. What I mean is that I have a bool on all of my game objects. When Object **A**'s bool is set to true during gameplay, I would like object **B** to be set to true and then **C** and so on for every game object that is in the chain. It should also work the other way around, so that if **A** is set to false again, all of the objects in the 'chain' are set to false.

[image]

I currently have a system where I add each currently colliding object to a list of gameObjects. But I have no idea how to create this  'knock on' effect where one object affects all of the objects in the chain.

Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: How about make all your Objects as children to one empty gameObject and you can trigger there your desired behavior. Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

What you show above can be described as a node, where each node has a child node (or nodes) and a parent node.

```
public class Node 
{ 
    public Node parentNode;
    public Node childNode; 

    public bool someBool;
}
```

Then you can use a recursive function to traverse the nodes.  Below is an example of traversal utilizing the child nodes.

```
public void SetBoolOnChildNodes(Node rootNode, bool value)
{
    if (rootNode != null)
    {
        rootNode.someBool = value;

        SetBoolOnChildNodes(rootNode.childNode, value);
    }
}
```

If order is not important, it would make sense to have the root object hold a list of all nodes and have each node hold reference to the root object.  Then you just set the boolean value using a loop constructed from the root objects node list.

```
public class Node2
{
    public Node2 rootNode; // Null for root node, populated for all others
    public List<Node2> nodes; // Populated only on root node (or all.. doesnt really matter other than memory)
    public bool someBool;
}

public void SetValueOnChildNodes(Node2 rootNode, bool value)
{
    if (rootNode == null) return;

    rootNode.someBool = value;

    foreach (var node in rootNode.nodes)
    {
        node.someBool = value;
    }
}
```